# Script to email if users "other than" login

Tags: login, scripting

I'm looking for an "alarm" script which will email if users other than those in a "authorised_users.txt" file log onto the VC 3 and/or esx 3 hosts. Allowed users can be created via VC permissions, however this would notify us if similiar role though unauthorised attempt to login.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Shane.

Comment: I think you'll get a better response for this on ServerFault. Don't repost it will get migrated if enough people agree. However, I think you will also need to provide a lot more information about the OS and environment you are using too.

Answer (score 6):

So you want to allow people to login who aren't allowed? Wouldn't it be easier just to deny them the ability to login?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script run through cron periodically to either run finger and see who is logged in, or to take a look at /var/log/wtmp and see who is/has logged in.

I'm with Matt though - why let them log-in at all?

Alternatively, you could alter the system .profile (/etc/profile) for all users, with a check in there to send an alert email and potentially log the user off, kill their session, etc.